# Intellij Rider: How to configure your run / debug configuration to execute another app exe with your dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, rider

Trying to setup rider to execute a compiled .exe program to run with my dll. My dll is a proxy dll. I know how the compiled dll looks like and it works fine when added to the project directory.

But now I want to debug it and it needs debug configuration so that it will be pointing to external exe, which will load my dll code while running.

In Visual Studio it is done from the Configuration Properties -> Debugging screen, where you can specify the path to the exe to use in Command option.

What is the equivalent for that option in Rider?

The dll I am trying to debug is written in c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is .NET Executable configuraiton for C++ projects. Simply specifying the path to an external exe file and specifying working directory to be the same directory where exe (and compiled dll) is, makes it work.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.